# Eclipse IDE different languages configuration

Tags: eclipse, configuration

my question may be silly but I am in a weird situation right now. I am currently using the latest edition of Eclipse IDE configured for android development ,downloaded from the android developers site. I am trying to install other languages to it like C++  and no matter what I do I get the binary not found when I try to compile a C++ programm. I installed different editions of compilers and I get the same problem .So here is my question:

Do I have to download a different edition of Eclipse to install the other languages or am I doing anything wrong?

Comment: Was a c++ compiler also installed and configured? Eclipse does not include a c++ compiler, just the editors etc.

Comment: Yes I downloaded a compiler and configured it from the preferences

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at this tutorial on how to ready eclipse for C++, perhaps it will help you locate your problem

[C++ for Eclipse](http://www.cis.gvsu.edu/~dulimarh/CS263/CDT-install/)